# Fitting Step functions

Tags: r

**AIM:** The aim here was to find a suitable fit, using step functions, which uses `age` to describe `wage`, in the `Wage` dataset in the library `ISLR`.

---

**PLAN:**

To find a suitable fit, I'll try multiple fits, which will have different cut points. I'll use the `glm()` function (of the `boot` library) for the fitting purpose. In order to check which fit is the best, I'll use the `cv.glm()` function to perform cross-validation over the fitted model.

---

**PROBLEM:**

In order to do so, I did the following:

```
all.cvs = rep(NA, 10)
for (i in 2:10) {
  lm.fit = glm(wage~cut(Wage$age,i), data=Wage)
  all.cvs[i] = cv.glm(Wage, lm.fit, K=10)$delta[2]
}
```

But this gives an error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = wage ~ cut(Wage$age, i), data =
list( :    variable lengths differ (found for 'cut(Wage$age, i)')
```

Whereas, when I run the code given below, it runs.(It can be found [here](http://blog.princehonest.com/stat-learning/ch7/6.html))

```
all.cvs = rep(NA, 10)

for (i in 2:10) {
  Wage$age.cut = cut(Wage$age, i)
  lm.fit = glm(wage~age.cut, data=Wage)
  all.cvs[i] = cv.glm(Wage, lm.fit, K=10)$delta[2]
}
```

---

**Hypotheses and Results:**

1. Well, it might be possible that `cut()` and `glm()` might not work together. But this works:

   ```
   glm(wage~cut(age,4),data=Wage)
   ```

---

**Question:**
So, basically we're using the `cut()` function, saving it's results in a variable, then using that variable in the `glm()` function. But we can't put the cut function inside the `glm()` function. And that too, only if the code is in a loop.

*So, why is the first version of the code not working?*

This is confusing. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `cv.glm` needs the same variables given as input of the `glm` function. Using `glm(wage~cut(age,4),data=Wage)` you create a new variable inside `glm` that is not available in `Wage`

Comment: @MarcoSandri So, since `cv.glm()` has `Wage` as an argument, therefore `glm()` can have **only** `Wage`'s attributes as it's formula's arguments. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Right ! `cv.glm` needs to "know" the variables used in the `glm` model.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190337/